# Maximum length of product of disjoint cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra

[This](http://mathsci.ucd.ie/modules/math30300/homework5-10-sols.pdf) proof concerning the largest possible order of a permutation in $S_{10}$ uses some theorem for inferring that in $S_{10}$ the length $k_1+...+k_n$ of a product of disjoint permutations $k_1, ..., k_n$ cannot exceed 10, i.e. $k_1+...+k_n≤10$.

What result is this?

Comment: Read again: *disjoint*

Comment: No theorem is needed: each of the cycles consists of elements of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, and the cycles are disjoint, so their total size cannot be more than $10$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't understand what that means in the context of permutations.

Comment: To get the order, find LCM of cycle sizes.

Comment: To a cyclic permutation (or in fact any permutation) we can assign the set of all elements of $\{1,\ldots,10\}$ that the permutation actually affects (i.e., the set of non-fixpoints). The cycles are called disjoint if their corresponding sets are disjoint.